# Recording from pc speakers; headset speakers; and microphone simultaneously

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, microphone

I'm using Windows 7.
While recording videos using Shadowplay (Recording gameplay basically) I can easily record the game sounds coming from the pc speakers and simultaneously record my own voice through the microphone. However, if I am playing with someone else and their voice comes through my headset speakers, I cannot figure out how to record this as well. How do I record the game sounds from my pc speakers; the voice from anyone I am playing with through my headset speakers; and my own voice through the microphone simultaneously?